# ~/.irbrc not executed when starting irb or script/console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, irb, rails-console

Here's what I've tried:

```
1. gem install awesome_print
2. echo "require 'ap'" >> ~/.irbrc
3. chmod u+x ~/.irbrc
4. script/console
5. ap { :test => 'value' }
```

Result:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `ap' for #
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Adding "require 'rubygems'" to my ~/.irbrc file seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 20):

To check what in .irbrc is failing, just execute .irbrc as a normal Ruby script (ruby ~/.irbrc), and Ruby will tell you which line fails. It might complain that IRB module is missing, just require 'irb' in the script (you only need this when testing it, not when actually running IRB).

Comment: Yupp, this definitely helped me debug my situation and lead to a fix. (I'm just puzzled that IRB didn't complain when loading irb when a gem was missing.)

Answer (score 12):

## Your Rails Console May Be Using Pry

Based on the suggestions that `~/.irbrc` must be invalid, I reduced mine to a single `puts "hi"`, and although it output when I ran `irb`, it did not when I ran `rails console`.

I finally noticed that the prompt was `pry(main)`. It turned out that this Rails project is set up with the `pry-rails` gem, so that's what the console uses. Customizing `.pryrc` does the trick.

Answer (score 7):

In my case it was "If your ~/.irbrc is invalid, it will fail
silently." - from Google search
- found and fixed errors in ~/.irbrc, all working fine

Comment: Had the same problem.  In particular, if there are any `require` statements at the top, and they don't work because of the bundler environment, the whole .irbrc will be ignored silently.  Solution: `begin / rescue Exception / end` blocks around everything that could fail.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `require 'rubygems'` as jdeseno wrote.

If you are on Rails3 and use Bundler, you also need to specify the 'awesome_print' gem in the Gemfile too (in the :development group) for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Do check whether the application is using Pry or Debug. For the former, edit .pryrc; the latter uses .irbrc.

You can edit .pryrc in your repository directory. The local directory and $HOME is scanned for the dot file.